# How to fix "variable not in scope" error in GHCI?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have programmed a really basic recursive function, but when I try to use it Haskell gives me an error.

This is the code:

```
import Data.Char
import Test.QuickCheck
potencia :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
potencia x 0 = 1
potencia x n = x*(potencia x (n-1))
```

And this is the error:

```
<interactive>:27:1-8: error:
    Variable not in scope: potencia :: Integer -> Integer -> t
```

If I delete the import of libreries it doesn´t give me the error anymore but I need them for later. I`m using the latest version of the Haskell platform.

Comment: If you define a multi-line function in an interactive shell, you have to use `:{` and `:}` or other measures.

Comment: Write your code in a .hs file, and load all of it from GHCi (or compile it).

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear" because the issue is omitted.  Between "the code:" and "the error:" should be "I ran:" and what you ran is undoubtably the issue since the code is fine.

Answer (score 8):

I see you are defining your function in interactive shell. Most of Haskell's REPLs read and eval instructions line-by-line, so when you type `potencia :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer` it is interpreted **right at this moment**, so compiler complains that potencia is lacking implementation. You should either:

- Define it in external file and load it using `:l` (recommended)
- Type `:set +m` and use `let` statement to define variable with respect to indentation
- Surround your definition with `:{` and `:}`
- Put whole definition and declaration in one line separating each part with `;`